# Modifying the Veins Earlengen Example

Tags: windows, text, omnet++, veins, sumo

I want to change the map in the Veins example. However, when I create random trips, the vehicles disappear before completing the route (or are not visible), so I created a SUMO simulation and defined routes where my specified vehicles only move on my created routes. But in this state, I couldn’t adapt it to the Veins example, whereas I can when there are random trips.

When I run omnetpp.ini, my map opens in SUMO-GUI, but the simulation screen becomes non-responsive, and the error isn’t specified.

My questions are:

1. What could be causing this error?
2. Can I run this example with custom routes, or does it have to be random trips?

Thank you very much for your support.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN2sB.png)

I configured a SUMO simulation with these custom routes and successfully observed the vehicles following them as intended within SUMO. When trying to integrate this setup into Veins and running it through OMNeT++, the SUMO interface opens correctly, but the simulation interface becomes unresponsive without providing an error message to indicate the problem's source.

When OMNeT++ becomes unresponsive and I close the SUMO window, I receive the following error: "<!> Connection to TraCI server lost. Check your server's log. Error message: 10054: Unknown error -- in module (veins::TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd) RSUExampleScenario.manager (id=6), at t=0s, event #1." There are no other specified errors. I am using Windows with OMNeT++ version 5.6.2, Veins version 5.2, and SUMO version 1.8.0.